# Can I lazy load content from an another page?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I have created a page that loads `<div>` contents from several other pages and displays them in one main page (much like a news website's main page).

I am using javascript `.load()` to bring in the external content.

The problem is: The more `.load()` items I add, the slower the main page loads.

I have looked at many articles about lazy loading and have not been able to find a scenario like mine. This leads me to believe that I'm taking the wrong approach to the problem. But I can't think of another way to lazy load external content.

Here is the basic code that I'm using to load the external `<div>` content from other pages.

```
<!--Use js to load external div contents from several pages-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#heading1").load("https://example.com/page1 #h1_1");
    $("#preview1").load("https://example.com/page1 #p1");
    $("#heading2").load("https://example.com/page2 #h1_1");
    $("#preview2").load("https://example.com/page2 #p1");
});
</script>
<!--Show first external page div contents-->
    <div id="heading1">
    </div>
    <div id="preview1">
    </div>
<!--Show second external page div contents-->
    <div id="heading2">
    </div>
    <div id="preview2">
    </div>
```

My question is: Is there a way to lazy load *external* `<div>` content from other pages one-by-one as a user scrolls down this main page?

Just like how Facebook will lazy load posts as you scroll down. Or how Youtube will lazy load comments as you scroll down.

Comment: You're talking specifically about jQuery lazy-loading, and `.load()` loads the images when the users scrolls the containing element into the viewport. Yes, there will be slight overheads to initial page load, but so small you shouldn't even notice them.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that once I add about 60 different `.load()` the page takes forever to populate. I am unsure how to lazy load this content so that a user will quickly see first `.load()` external content, and then when/if they scroll down they will see the additional `.load()` content. I feel as though I'm in over my head.